# Parse Values from String Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

Trying to find the most efficient way to extract values from a large string.

```
EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="PreRoll_Ident_Open",START-DATE="2016-12-14T120000.000z",DURATION=3,X-PlayHeadStart="0.000",X-AdID="AA-1QPN49M9H2112",X-TRANSACTION-VPRN-ID="1486060788",X-TrackingDefault="1",X-TrackingDefaultURI="http,//606ca.v.fwmrm.net/ad/l/1?s=g015&n=394953%3B394953&t=1485791181366184015&f=&r=394953&adid=15914070&reid=5469372&arid=0&auid=&cn=defaultImpression&et=i&_cc=15914070,5469372,,,1485791181,1&tpos=0&iw=&uxnw=394953&uxss=sg579054&uxct=4&metr=1031&init=1&vcid2=394953%3A466c5842-0cce-4a16-9f8b-a428e479b875&cr="s=0&iw=&uxnw=394953&uxss=sg579054&uxct=4&metr=1031&init=1&vcid2=394953%3A466c5842-0cce-4a16-9f8b-a428e479b875&cr="
```

I have the above as an example. 
The idea is to extract all caps string before : as object key, and everything in between quotes until next comma as its value. Then iterate entire string until this object is created.

```
nonParsed.substring(nonParsed.lastIndexOf("="")+1, nonParsed.lastIndexOf("","));
```

I had this concept as a start, but some help iterating through this and making it more efficient would be appreciated.

Final output would be something like --

```
{
  'EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID': 'PreRoll_Ident_Open',
  'START-DATE': '2016-12-14T120000.000z',
  'DURATION': '3',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: It'll be a little tougher than usual since you seem to have a comma in your X-TrackingDefaultURI header value where the colon should be. This will make a naive split more difficult.

Comment: What would be the final output?

Comment: @revo I updated with sample object

Comment: *The idea is to extract all caps string before `:` ...* so why doesn't it apply to `EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID` which should extract `EXT-X-DATERANGE` part only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only property that messes up a predictable pattern is `DURATION`, which is followed by a number. Otherwise, you can rely on a naive pattern of alternating `="` and `",`.

You could do something like

```
str = str.replace(/DURATION=(\d+)/, `DURATION="$1"`);
return str.split('",').reduce((acc, entry) => {
    let key = `'${entry.split('="')[0]}'`;
    let value = `'${entry.split('="')[1]}'`;
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Then add a bit of logic to the end to sort out the Duration if you needed to.

Comment: this is great! i can sanitize before this filter, so i can have duration follow the same string rules as the others

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have mixed case strings for the headers, not just uppercase. I would instead look for key-value pairs based on the = character. You can construct a regex and use the exec() method to then iterate and build your object.

```
var input = 'EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="PreRoll_Ident_Open",START-DATE="2016-12-14T120000.000z",DURATION=3,X-PlayHeadStart="0.000",X-AdID="AA-1QPN49M9H2112",X-TRANSACTION-VPRN-ID="1486060788",X-TrackingDefault="1",X-TrackingDefaultURI="http,//606ca.v.fwmrm.net/ad/l/1?s=g015&n=394953%3B394953&t=1485791181366184015&f=&r=394953&adid=15914070&reid=5469372&arid=0&auid=&cn=defaultImpression&et=i&_cc=15914070,5469372,,,1485791181,1&tpos=0&iw=&uxnw=394953&uxss=sg579054&uxct=4&metr=1031&init=1&vcid2=394953%3A466c5842-0cce-4a16-9f8b-a428e479b875&cr="s=0&iw=&uxnw=394953&uxss=sg579054&uxct=4&metr=1031&init=1&vcid2=394953%3A466c5842-0cce-4a16-9f8b-a428e479b875&cr='

// Regex looks for any alpha character, colon, or hyphen before a =, then captures anything between the quotes and an optional comma after
var pattern = /([A-Za-z:-]+)="([^"]+)",?/g;

// Iterate the string using exec() and build the object along the way
var match;
var output = {};
while (match = pattern.exec(input)) {
    output[match[1]] = match[2];
}

console.dir(output);
```

Comment: May I suggest `/(?:^|,)([A-Za-z\-]+?)(?::[A-Z\-]+)?=(".+?"|\d+?)(?=,|$)/gm` as a more comprehensive regex? https://regex101.com/r/5XLR1O/1

Comment: it allows capture of that messy URL and the unquoted integer values

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.  You split the string on the double quotes (this of course presumes that you do not have an escaped double quote within a value). Then you cycle through the resulting array setting the ith value to the key and the ith+1 value to the value of that key.  Here would be the code:

```
strings=nonparsed.split('"');
myObj={};
myObj[strings[0].slice(0,-1)]=strings[1];
for(i=2;i<strings.length;i+=2)myObj[strings[i].slice(1,-1)]=strings[i+1];
```